# How can I add a feature using torchtext?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, pipeline, torchtext

`torchtext` is able to read a file with some columns, each one corresponding to a field. What if I want to create a new column (which I will use as a feature)? For example, imagine the file has two columns, text and target, and I want to extract some information from the text and generate a new feature (e.g. if it contains certain words), can I do this directly with `torchtext` or do I need to do it in the file before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.

```py
def postprocessing(arr,vocab,pad_token):
    # required to pad the sequence
    max_len = max([len(a) for a in arr])
    l = []
    for a in arr:
        res = max_len - len(a)
        if res > 0:
            a.extend([[pad_token]*len(a[0])]*res)
        l.append(a)
    return l

def featurization(text_list):
    # creates character level features
    # text_list is a list of characters.
    features = []
    for ch in text_list:
        l = []
        l.append(1 if ch.isupper() else 0)
        l.append(1 if ch in string.digits else 0)
        l.append(1 if ch in string.punctuation else 0)
        features.append(l)
    return features

temp_data = pd.read_csv("../data/processed/data.csv")
```

The below step is necessary to take only those columns which we want to process and the column order matters

```py
temp_data.loc[:,["text","label"]].to_csv("temp.csv",index=False)
```

Create the Text, Feature, and Target fields. Here I am tokenizing a sentence into characters.

```py
TEXT = torchtext.data.Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True,
                               tokenize=lambda x: list(x), include_lengths=True,
                               batch_first=True)
    

LABEL_PAD_TOKEN=-1
FEAT = torchtext.data.LabelField(use_vocab=False,batch_first=True,preprocessing=featurization,
                                    pad_token=None,postprocessing=lambda x, _:postprocessing(x,_,LABEL_PAD_TOKEN))

LABELS = torchtext.data.Field(use_vocab=False,pad_token=LABEL_PAD_TOKEN,unk_token=None,
                                  batch_first=True,dtype=torch.int64,tokenize=lambda x: list(x),
                                 preprocessing=lambda x:[eval(i) for i in x])
```

In the TabularDataset, the correct field order should be given matching the temp.csv column order.

```py
train_data = torchtext.data.TabularDataset(path="temp.csv",format="csv",skip_header=True,
                                               fields=[(("text","feat"),(TEXT,FEAT)),
                                                       ("labels",LABELS)])
TEXT.build_vocab(train_data)
    
train_data,valid_data = train_data.split() # create train val
```

Build the iterator

```py
   train_iter,valid_iter=torchtext.data.BucketIterator.splits((train_data,valid_data,),batch_size=2,device=device                                                                  ,sort_within_batch=True,sort_key=lambda x:len(x.text))
            
a = next(iter(train_iter))
a.feat.shape, a.text[0].shape   # printing the shape
```

`(torch.Size([2, 36, 3]), torch.Size([2, 36]))`

Next, you can pass the text to the embedding layer whose `input` is `[batch_size, seq_len]`
which will `output` `[batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim]`

The features have the shape of `[batch_size, seq_len,3]` because we have 3 features

Concatenate both of these on last dimension giving `[batch_size, seq_len, emb_dim+3]` and pass it either to LSTM or CNN